# Network wide post count (WP Multisite)

Tags: posts, count, statistics

I'm trying to show the total amount of posts of my WordPress Multisite. For that I'm using the following code, which worked at the beginning. So I guess that there's something wrong with the `set_site_transient` which should cache the output for a time.

Maybe someone has an idea what my mistake is. I can't find the solution.

Cheers and thanks a lot!

```
    function posts_count_func( $args ){

    global $wpdb;
    $blogs = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->blogs} WHERE  spam = '0' 
            AND deleted = '0' AND archived = '0' 
            ORDER BY registered DESC, 2", ARRAY_A ) );

    $original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

     $args = array(
        'numberposts'     => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'post',
        'post_status'     => 'publish' );
    $total_network = $draft_network = 0;
    $total_sites = 0;

    foreach ($blogs as $blog)
    {
        wp_cache_flush();
        switch_to_blog( $blog->blog_id );
        $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
        if (count(get_posts($args))<2) { continue; }
        $total_posts = count( get_posts( $args ) );
        $total_network += $total_posts;
        $total_sites += 1;

        $args['post_status'] = 'draft';

        }

        set_site_transient ( 'total_posts_cache', $total_network, 24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );



 switch_to_blog( $original_blog_id );
}

function posts_shortcode_count_func( $atts ){
 return get_site_transient( 'total_posts_cache' );
}
add_shortcode( 'posts', 'posts_shortcode_count_func' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to call `posts_count_func()` anywhere, so if your transient expires, it's not getting reset.

```
function posts_shortcode_count_func( $atts ){
    $post_count = get_site_transient( 'total_posts_cache' );
    if( ! $post_count ) {
        posts_count_func();
        $post_count = get_site_transient( 'total_posts_cache' );
    }
    return $post_count;
}
add_shortcode( 'posts', 'posts_shortcode_count_func' );
```

According to the [docs for `get_transient()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_transient) (which is the non-network version of `get_site_transient()`), `false` is returned if the transient doesn't exist or has expired.

**Also:** You shouldn't need `$args['post_status'] = 'publish';` in your `foreach()` loop, since you've already set that key=>value pair in your `$args` array up higher.

Comment: Ahhh! Yes! Thank you so much!
Should I use get_transient() instead of get_site_transient()?

Comment: No, for your case, use `get_site_transient()` -- I linked to `get_transient()` because the page for `get_site_transient()` essentially says "See `get_transient()` for details".

Comment: @ Pat J: Thank you very much. I'm still struggeling and opened a new question. If it's possible to you it would be great if you could take another look here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107244/wp-cron-doesnt-do-the-job-multisite-stats